# в поле len в БД вписывается array вместо Тест1.Почему?

Tags: php

> Название и описание отправляется а в поле len пустота.Почему?

```
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "regauth") or die("Error!!!");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    header("location: ../../");

if($_GET['link'] === 'logout'){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../../");
}

  $len=($_POST['nameselect']);
   $name_z=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name_z']));
    $op=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['op']));


    if(isset($_POST['do-len'])){
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (login,password,name,email,img,len,name_z,op) VALUES ('$login', '$password','$name','$email','$img','$len','$name_z','$op') ");  
 }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Личный кабинет</title>
</head>

<body>
<div><?php echo "Привет, ".$_SESSION['user'][1]; ?> | <a href="index.php?link=logout">Выйти</a>
</div>
<h3>Создание заявки</h3>
<form  method="post">

  <label>Название<br><input type="text" name="name_z"></label><br>
  Описание<br><textarea name="op" cols="21"></textarea>

<p><select size="3" name="nameselect[]" multiple>
    <option value="Тест1">Тест1</option>
    <option value="Тест2">Тест2</option>
    <option value="Тест3">Тест3</option>
   </select></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="do-len"value="Отправить"></p>
   </form>
   <h3>Просмотр своей заяки</h3>
  <?php

$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `len` = '$len'");
$result = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['len'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Вам же прям в ошибке написали. nameselect[] - $_POST['nameselect'] - вы  пытаетесь в trim засунуть массив. Это так не работает, на trim можно только строку подать.

Comment: дело не в этом я убирал  trim но все равно в поле len нет  записи в бд

Comment: Вы делаете свой селект таким, чтобы можно было выбрать много значений: `<select size="3" name="nameselect[]" multiple>`. Затем вы получаете их: `$len=$_POST['nameselect']`. Значит в $len - **МАССИВ** выбранных значений. Даже если выбрали одно, это все равно массив и обращаться к нему надо, как к массиву, а не как попало.

Comment: Дальше. В запросе `INSERT INTO...` вы никак не обрабатываете случай, когда выбрали много значений. Может уже вам оно и не нужно, выбор многих значений??? Напишите `<select size="3" name="nameselect">` и не мучайтесь.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов вам пора начать писать обучающие книги вы наверное единственный кто доходчиво все обьясняет)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов вы как обычно меня выручили)